# Create a single source project with full .net, PCL and dotnet core assemblies build from same C# source?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-standard-1.5

Update: This refers to an obsolete set of .net core tools built around project.json, this question and its answers are of very limited utility in current .net core toolsets like Visual Studio 2017+.

Using Visual Studio 2015, update 3, I am trying to find out the current limitations that exist that would prevent me from doing the following:

1. For a single C# codebase, compile a full .net framework version and a PCL version, and a .net core class library from the same sources.
2. Solution dir `solutiondir\` will contain a `src\` dir which contains a `projectdir\` (`Solutiondir\src\projectdir`).
3. `Projectdir` will contain a *HelloWorldPCL* class library which is built as a `classic .net PCL` project, and with other framework targets as well.
4. From the same `Projectdir` the same *HelloWorldPCL* will also be compiled for  `.net 4.6` project.
5. From the same `Projectdir` the same *HelloWorldPCL* will also be compiled for `.net core`.
6. All of the output assemblies above will share access to a single set of C# code which may have some `#if DOTNET` and `#if NET46` and `#if PCL` conditional defines to handle things which are not available in various frameworks/environments.

So far I can do most of the above, but when I try to have the `Projectdir` contain a `.net core` artifact like `project.json` or `HelloWorldCore.xproj`, the IDE gives me many errors if I try to create separate `.csproj` and `.xproj` projects in the same folder, so that appears not to be the right way to go.

With a working `.csproj` project when I introduce an `.xproj` and a `project.json` on disk, but we have not added these to the solution itself, they are just sitting there on the disk beside the Real Project Sources, I get a Nuget package restore error, which can only be made to go away by deleting the `project.json` file, so clearly it is not possible to have a `.csproj` in a project directory and also have a `project.json` folder. One must choose between `project.json` mode (`.net core` project style) and `.csproj` mode (classic C# project style).

I have built a "broken" codebase that demonstrates the impossibility of using a folder containing both a `.csproj` and a `project.json` and then trying to build the `csproj` and `project.json` project without them interfering:

https://bitbucket.org/wpostma/helloworldcoreandpcl

**Question**: is there ANY way to build a project from a single set of C# source files, and have as your targets, a full `.net 4.6` assembly, and also a native `.net core` class library, and also a PCL assembly which might target any particular .net profile?

**Objection:** You may rightly ask "shouldn't you just use one PCL and have done with it, and forget targeting full .net or creating a separate `.net core` class library dll?".  Maybe if the code could be built once, from a single source, without any conditional defines, and without any differences in functionality and if the limitations imposed by a lowest-common-denominator PCL "*netstandard*" profile approach were sufficient, you could. But what about the cases where that's not even possible?

Do we have to have some elaborate build process where we either copy project files or move source code around, in order to achieve single `.cs` source file  target multiple .net profile nerdvana?  Or am I overlooking alternative solutions?

**Update**: It appears there is a problem with the Visual Studio IDE that prevents you from directly adding a reference to a class library in your solution, when you build it with a `project.json` instead of using a `.csproj`.  However the solution below specified by Jon indicates that you should build your project, then build a nuget package with `dotnet pack`.  If you look at my modified demo here you can the [pack.cmd](https://bitbucket.org/wpostma/helloworldcoreandpclv2/src/3ac94934f28329ff06c77273b7b602c64256c6e1/HelloWorldPCL/pack.cmd?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) file contains the steps I used to pack up a nuget package, and then locally "publish" it to a file (local directory) nuget feed for my own personal use.

Comment: For a more concrete example consider this codebase where I am trying to create native .net core class library targets, on a codebase which currently has dual PCL and full-net solutions doing two thirds of what I wanted to do in the question above...  https://github.com/wpostma/fhir-net-api

Comment: Why have three different project files? I think you can do all of this with a single `project.json` which supports the three different frameworks. (And you can have different build options for the different frameworks, too...)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148363 for some help with targeting PCL from project.json

Comment: Yes, I believe it should all work. It's a bit of a "road less travelled" though.

Comment: Will see if I can come up with a complete example. Which PCL profile are you targeting?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the profile selected above" - but that solution seems to be needlessly complicated with lots of folders etc. Will still try to add an answer...

Comment: [25k and an image of your errors.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)  There should be a ceremony where we [rip the rep off your uniform](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InsigniaRipOffRitual) and send you out into the desert on a donkey.

Comment: The screenshot is in the end not relevant, deleted.

Comment: Interesting blog post: http://stackify.com/using-both-xproj-and-csproj-with-net-core/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try to go for a pure `project.json` approach. For example, here's a `project.json` file which will build a single package which supports `netstandard1.0`, PCL profile 328, and .NET 4.6 - with each configuration defining its own symbols so you can have conditional code.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [ "NET46" ]
      }
    },

    "netstandard1.0": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [ "CORE" ]
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      }
    },

    ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile328": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [ "PCL" ]
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
         "mscorlib": "",
         "System": "",
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Then just use `dotnet pack` to create the nuget package. (After adding in all the other metadata etc.)

Comment: @WarrenP: Will try to reproduce. Although note that within the same solution, I typically use a `"target": "project"` dependency, to avoid having to specify the version number.

Comment: @WarrenP: Why do you have four different projects in your sample? It would make it easier to understand what's going on if you just had two: a class library with a project.json as per my answer, then a console app trying to consume it... (In particular, which project is failing? It sounds like this may be an issue with csproj projects failing to consume project.json projects. You should try either making everything project.json-based, or pack the class library into a nuget package, put it in a local package source, and depend on that.)

Comment: @WarrenP: Well, I'd check that the resulting project.json is what you'd want it to be. A bit of diligence early in can pay dividends in maintainability later on.

Comment: @WarrenP: From what kind of project? Maybe it's worth asking a second question where you give the specifics. I'm sure we can make this work :)

Comment: Okay. Full source code of my example, fixed as per Jon's instructions above, is working fine... Code is found here:

https://bitbucket.org/wpostma/helloworldcoreandpclv2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use xproj and csproj together with different project.json files. I did a blog post on the topic you should check out: http://stackify.com/using-both-xproj-and-csproj-with-net-core/

Essentially, you create a projectname.project.json that csproj picks up and then project.json that xproj uses. Seems to work!

Comment: Thanks. That's a useful technique!