# Compiler directives for targeting several frameworks using .NET Core

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core

I have a library targeting `.NET Core` and `net45` at some point on my code I need to use reflection like this:

```
var type = obj.GetType();
var properties = type.GetProperties().ToList();

if (type.IsPrimitive || type.IsEnum || properties.Count == 0)
    return new Dictionary<string, object> { { unnamed, obj } };
```

Now I am porting my library to also support `.net core` so I made a new `.net core library` project, this is my `project.json`

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "Wen.Logging.Abstractions": "1.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net45": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Reflection": "4.0.0.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.4",
        "NLog": "4.3.5"
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
        "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2",
        "NLog": "4.4.0-*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Added my classes and the compiler complains about the `type.IsPrimitive` and `types.IsEnum` properties so I thought to use compiler directives to do something like this:

```
var type = obj.GetType();
var properties = type.GetProperties().ToList();

#if net45    

if (type.IsPrimitive || type.IsEnum || properties.Count == 0)
    return new Dictionary<string, object> { { unnamed, obj } };

#elif netstandard16

//... some code

#endif
```

Once I do this the code inside the `net45` is grayed out (I think because VS is seeing it as `.net core`) but then no matter what tag I set between the `#elif` and `#endif` is also grayed. I have also tried with `#else` and then I can do:

```
var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
if(typeInfo.IsPrimitive || typeInfo.IsEnum || properties.Count == 0)
    return new Dictionary<string, object> { { unnamed, obj } };
```

However my question remains:

What *tags* should I use on my code on the compiler directives `#if` to target several frameworks on the same project/library?

Comment: @JonSkeet the post was created one year ago, so such attempt was acceptable. I agree today nobody should go that way any more.

Comment: @LexLi: Good point - I only saw it because it was edited 3 hours ago. Will remove my comment...

Answer (score 0):

While doing some research on `.net core` I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206209/create-a-single-source-project-with-full-net-pcl-and-dotnet-core-assemblies-bu) and in the accepted answer there is something in the `project.json` file code that caught my eye, here is a snippet:

```
"frameworks": {
"net46": {
  "buildOptions": {
    "define": [ "NET46" ]
  }
},
```

as you can see inside the `buildOptions` there is a `define: [ NET46 ]` which is the tag you can use along the `#if` and `#elif` directives. So even if I don't know (or there isn't) a way to refer to those versions of the framework I could use my own.

Comment: Anyone using the latest .NET Core SDK tooling should follow this official article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks, to use builtin defined symbols, instead of defining your own.